# Number of solutions of $|\log_e{|x-2|}|+x^2-2x-35=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

> Find the number of solutions of the given equation:
> $$|\log_e{|x-2|}|+x^2-2x-35=0$$

While studying the topic "Graph Transformation", this question cam up and the answer was said as 4.

Out of curiosity, I went to Geogebra, and there I saw the answer should be 2 instead! 
[Here's my simple attempt](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kefxvsqr) in GeoGebra for confirmation.

1. Isn't there a way that complements the graph so as to confirm the answer?
2. How can this question be solved without the use of graphs?

Please help.

Comment: The GeoGebra graph is misleading.  Your log function has a vertical asymptote at x=2.  This means as x approaches 2, the value of your log function gets arbitrarily large.  Your log function will intersect your quadratic at two points that are not shown, one point is where x is slightly less than 2, the other point is where x is slightly more than 2.

Comment: God have mercy on the souls who try to solve this algebraically

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Oh, alright.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational so there's no way to confirm that I'll indeed get 4 solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so the trick to dealing with the question is to begin by figuring out **where the solution can exist** rather than **where exactly the solution is**.

We can rearrange the equation as:

$$ | \log_e |x-2| | = -(x^2 - 2x -35)$$

The reason I did this was that I have an absolute value, rearranging like this tells me I have to focus only on the part where RHS is positive. So, we have to solve the inequality:

$$  -(x^2 - 2x - 35) \geq 0 \iff x^2 - 2x -35 \leq 0$$

Now, I'll tell you are pretty uncommon trick: Consider the quadratic $q(x)= x^2 - 2x -35$, if we consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} q(x)$ then we it should be that the $x^2$ term dominates the value. Since the $x^2$ term has positive coefficient, $ \lim_{ x \to \infty} q(x)$ is some positive value. This means that the whole quadratic is negative in the region between the roots (it's in some finite place of $\mathbb{R}$). I find the solution as:

$$ - 5 \leq x \leq 7 \tag{1}$$

Before removing the absolute value on LHS, we have to see when the function is positive and when it's negative. We have :

$$- \log_e |x-2|  \leq 0 \iff |x-2| \leq 1 \iff 1 \leq x \leq 3  \tag{2}$$

And,

$$ \log_e |x-2| > 0 \iff |x-2|>1 \tag{3}$$

---

Now, since domain must work for both sides, we have to intersect (1) with (2) and intersect (1) with (3), and simplfy.

1. On the interval $[1,2)\cup(2,3]$, we have:

$$- \log_e (|x-2|) = - (x+5)(x-7)$$

2. On the interval $ \left(-5,1 \right]  \cup \left[3,7\right)$ , we have:

$$ \log_e (|x-2|) = -(x^2 -2x -35) $$

Now, we can split into further sub cases by expanding out the piece input and then use increasing/ decreasing arguments on the simplfied subsets to solve. Or, one can directly go for a graphical solution after (1):
[image]

(1) told me how the parabola looks like, and then it's just drawing grap hof $\log_e$ using experience.